# how to redirect one area to another area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two controllers in my MVC4 Project.
One controller is in default controller name called `Login`.
another controller is in area .area name called `HR`.inside controller name called `AddNewHire`.
inside AddNewHire i written `AddNewEmployee` method.

in Login controller i am having one method .that name is LoginButton

inside  LoginButton method i written

```
return RedirectToAction("AddNewEmployee","AddNewHire",new {area="HR"});
```

am getting Error Like

```
 Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

Requested URL: /AddNewHireController/AddNewEmployee

Comment: Please post your AddNewEmployee and Login name actionmethods

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RedirectToRoute` instead of `RedirectToAction`. What you would have to do is to define a route. Have a look at this MSDN link (Walkthrough: Creating an ASP.NET MVC Areas Application Using [Multiple Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987%28VS.100%29.aspx#registering_routes_in_account_and_store_areas)

Comment: return Redirect(url.content("HR/AddNewHire/AddNewEmployee"));

Comment: i got answer  
return Redirect(url.content("HR/AddNewHire/AddNewEmployee"));


Its working fine..